# Could not scan for classes inside

Tags: magento2

i am running composer install command but getting this error how i can fix this error need help thanks
[RuntimeException]

> Could not scan for classes inside
> "/var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php"
> which does not appear      to be a file nor a folder

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past and it was all due to something wrong with `composer.lock` file.

I would suggest you backup this file, delete it and then run composer install.

This will inevitably update all your composer packages BUT you don't have to commit those changes into your repository if you don't want/need to.

Instead, try compare the 2 versions of the `composer.lock` to find what the issue is.